# sql length(null)

Tags: sql, oracle, null, string-concatenation

I have two columns: p.firstName and p.lastName.

Now I want to display the length of both names combined, the problem is, that in some fields of p.lastName the value "null" is stored.

When I try to do it like this:

```
LENGTH(p.firstName + p.lastName)
```

I get an error:

```
ORA-01722 invalid number
```

However, if I split it up

```
LENGTH(p.firstName) + LENGTH(p.lastName)
```

it doesn't give me an error message. But the length of the sum is NULL, even if the firstName does have a few characters. The NULL of p.LastName breaks it so to say.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: `p.firstName + p.lastName` is invalid standard SQL (the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`) - which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I'm using oracle.

Comment: Oracle will not allow you to concatenate strings using `+` - that's for numbers. You need to use `||`

Comment: Thank you I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can Use IFNULL(), ISNULL(), COALESCE(), and NVL() Functions**

```
SELECT LENGTH(COALESCE(p.firstName,'') + COALESCE(p.lastName,'')) AS Len FROM TableName
```

**OR**

```
SELECT LENGTH(ISNULL(p.firstName,'') + ISNULL(p.lastName,'')) AS Len FROM TableName
```

**OR**

```
SELECT LENGTH(IFNULL(p.firstName,'') + IFNULL(p.lastName,'')) AS Len FROM TableName
```

**OR**

```
SELECT LENGTH(NVL(p.firstName,'') + NVL(p.lastName,'')) AS Len FROM TableName
```

**OR**

```
SELECT LENGTH(p.firstName || p.lastName) AS Len FROM TableName
```

Comment: COALESCE doesn't work.IFNULL does work, thank you my friend

Comment: Welcome @l.schwarz If You got your answer please accept and Up-vote

Comment: @l.schwarz: afaik Oracle doesn't have a `IFNULL` function, so what's the DBMS you're using?

Comment: The `COALESCE` option won't work on Oracle, q.v. Don's comments under my now deleted answer.

Comment: I Know Op didn't added DBMS at that time so I put all the functions @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: In Oracle *none* of those variations will work, either because of `NULL=''` or because those functions don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You may to concat columns instead using `||` operator:

```
LENGTH(p.firstName || p.lastName)
```

Example:

```
select ('abc'||null||'d') from dual; -- abcd
select length('abc'||null||'d') from dual; -- 4
```

Comment: `LENGTH( NULL || NULL )` will output `NULL` - it is unclear whether the OP expects this or `0` as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select case when p.firstname is null then 0 else length(p.firstName) end + 
  case when p.lastName is null then 0 else 
  length(nickname) end from p
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of what happens if `firstName` is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle usually treats an empty string as NULL:

```
COALESCE(LENGTH(p.firstName), 0) + COALESCE(LENGTH(p.lastName),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much better to use it this way...

```
SELECT LENGTH(ISNULL(p.firstName,'') + ISNULL(p.lastName,'')) AS length FROM TableName
```

Comment: In Oracle, `ISNULL()` is not a function; an empty string is equivalent to `NULL`; and `+` is the addition operator and does not concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Oracle behaves differently in the dealing of blank characters:

```
---------Oracle
SELECT LENGTH('') , LENGTH(null) FROM DUAL
--result: null,null

---------Postgress
SELECT LENGTH('') , LENGTH(null)
--result: 0,null

---------SQL Server
SELECT LEN('') , LEN(null)
--result: 0,null

---------MySQL
SELECT LENGTH('') , LENGTH(null)
--result: 0,null
```